# Artifacts using denoise

Tags: rendering, denoise

I did [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQBk1Uk0Gfk), and when I render there is an artifact like in the image below.

I'm using the last macOS with an AMD 560, and if I don't include denoising everything is fine. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem? If I render on the processor with denoising then everything is in order. How does the problem relate to the graphics card?

Or how could I set up denoising so that there would not be such an artifact?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the scene and settings? It is hard to tell from that little bit of image alone. Probably a denoiser bug

Comment: Please add more detail to your question (and consider sharing the .blend file). What settings are you using for the denoiser?

Comment: I have seen artifacts with using the Denoiser with the *Glossy Direct Pass* so I usually turn that pass off.